# Error At Drawing A Bufferedimage In Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to draw a `BufferedImage` using Java graphics. In my previous experiences, it worked many times, but now I don't know why eclipse is giving me an error.

It gives me this error:

> The method drawImage(BufferedImage, int, int, null) is undefined for
>   the type Graphics

```
public void render(Graphics g){

    g.drawImage(ss1[1],30,80,null);
}
```

In the above code, `ss1[]` is an array of `BufferedImage`

Comment: You might be use other implementation of the Graphics object as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032625/cant-draw-a-buffered-image.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that there is not a method with that signature.

Are you sure there is a `drawImage` that accepts a `BufferedImage`, an `int`, another `int` and `Object`?

Comment: [`Graphics#drawImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) expects a `java.awt.Image`, which `BufferedImage` extends from...

Comment: Nothing assures us that the `BufferedImage` he refers to is the one extending `java.awt.Image`.

Comment: Nothing assures as that the `Graphics` is the `java.awt.Graphics` either

Comment: Absolutely true as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver)`in Graphics - which should match your call as pointed out by @MadProgrammer.

I suggest you try to call `Graphics2D#drawImage(BufferedImage img, BufferedImageOp op, int x, int y)`.

As Graphics is usually a Graphics2D, you should be able to call

```
((Graphics2D)g).drawImage(ss1[1],null, 30,30);
```

While I am unsure if you can leave the ImageOp null.

Hm, but maybe your issue is rather the same as this person's? [Can't draw a Buffered Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032625/cant-draw-a-buffered-image)

Comment: I beg to differ [`Graphics#drawImage(java.awt.Image, int, int, java.awt.image.ImageObserver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)), since `BufferedImage` extends, it should work just fine

Comment: thank you sir, it worked when i added ((Graphics2D)g)  ,but its realy strange ,i always use it without ((Graphics2D)g) and it works.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree, will edit my answer, but as it worked for the op, it stays unexplained why

Comment: @thst I would guess that they aren't using `java.awt.Graphics`, which is going to result in some interesting results when they run it

Comment: @MALLEKMIROX can you call the drawIMage as you expected, if you cast the null to ImageObserver?